# MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool - target machine actively refuses connection

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to reuse sessions with Remote but I have an error...

Code :

```
session_url = "http://127.0.0.1:xxxxx"#retrieved from previous app launch
browser = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=session_url)
```

Error :

> MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=xxxxx): Max retries exceeded with url: /session (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

Help please. I have obfuscated the port with "xxxxx" for this post.

Answer (score 0):

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

you should check the target machine if it can be connected.

i have met the trouble but the error is
[Errno 111] Connection refused
i found the package httptools has not downloaded yet, maybe you can try it.